# Exact matching words in sentence and words in dictionaries in R

Tags: r

I have following data.frame with sentences and pos/negWords which represent dictionaries:

```
sent <- data.frame(words = c("just right size and i love this notebook", "benefits great laptop",
                         "wouldnt bad notebook", "very good quality", "orgtop",
                         "great improvement for that bad product but overall is not good", "notebook is not good but i love batterytop"), user = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               stringsAsFactors=F)

posWords <- c("great","improvement","love","great improvement","very good","good","right","very","benefits",
          "extra","benefit","top","extraordinarily","extraordinary","super","benefits super","good","benefits great")
negWords <- c("hate","bad","not good","horrible")
```

Then I have a script, which is matching words in sentences with pos/negWords in dictionaries. When words are matched, algorithm choose words in nearest neighbor of that matched pos/negWords - I mean +/- 2 words from matched pos/neg word in particular sentence:

```
counter <- 0
dataOut <- ldply(strsplit(as.character(sent$words), " "), 
             function(x) {
               counter <<- counter + 1
               p = which(x %in% posWords)
               n = which(x %in% negWords)
               positive <- vapply(p, function(i) paste0(c(x[i - 2], x[i - 1], x[i], x[i + 1], x[i + 2]), collapse = " "), character(1))
               negative <- vapply(n, function(i) paste0(c(x[i - 2], x[i - 1], x[i], x[i + 1], x[i + 2]), collapse = " "), character(1))
               if(length(positive) > 0 | length(negative) > 0) {
                 cbind(user = counter, word = c(positive, negative), val = rep(c(1, -1), c(length(p), length(n))))
               }
             })
```

But the problem is, that I want exact match to avoid something like this e.g. "is not good" - algorithm chooses good and evaluate it as a positive with +1 and then select nearest neighbors (+/- words from that matched word). But if I put "is not good" into the negative dictionary, I need to have it with -1 and then search nearest neighbor from that multiple term.

Problem in my approach is this part:

```
strsplit(as.character(sent$words), " ")
```

which spit words in each sentece as an unique. This is a problem when I'm not able to do exact match...

Please, could anyone help me with that. I really don't know, how to do that. I'll appreciate any of your help or advice. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are many polarity algorithms already implemented for R including Matthew Jockeys new GitHub package to do so.  Have you looked into existing implementations?

Comment: Yes, I looked at github and walked through a lot of web pages and didn't find anything similar :-(